# SolR indexing using Alfresco SDK 3.4

Tags: solr, lucene, alfresco

We are using lucene indexing and deploying alfresco 3.4 war using Alfresco SDK 3.4

Now we aim to use an Solr indexing and deploying another alfresco war (alfresco 4.2) but still remaining Alfresco SDK 3.4

My question is: can we use an Solr indexing even with Alfresco SDK 3.4?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR - No

From the [Alfresco and SOLR wiki page](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_And_SOLR):

> From Alfresco 4.0, Solr is available to support search within the Alfresco repository.

In order for Alfresco to support indexing and searching through an external SOLR instance, rather than with the existing in-transactional same-JVM Lucene index support, took quite a lot of work. This was one of the big changes in Alfresco 4.0.

From Alfresco 4.0 onwards, you have a choice between using SOLR, or the old-style in-transactional Lucene indexing. 3.x (and before!) only support in-transactional Lucene. None of the code needed to support SOLR is in 3.x